# All Swift BrightFuture callbacks happen on the main thread, right?

Tags: swift, asynchronous

When we make an asynchronous request using BrightFutures.

```
service.makeSomeRequest(
    param1: value1,
    param2: value2
)
.onSuccess { [weak self] result in
    ...
}
.onFailure { [weak self] error in
    ...
}
```

Which threading context will the respective `...` blocks run in?

My understanding is that they will always be on `main` thread, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, found [this helpful article](https://morioh.com/p/c1955242b90b) documenting the expected behavior:

- If the method is called from the main thread, the block is executed on the main queue
- If the method is not called from the main thread, the block is executed on a global queue

So basically, the context in which the `.onSuccess(...)` and `.onFailure(...)` callbacks will be executed depends on the original context in which the `service.makeSomeRequest(...)` was called.